# Removing multiple classes (jQuery)

Tags: jquery, css

Is there any better way to rewrite this:

```
$('element').removeClass('class1').removeClass('class2');
```

I cannot use **`removeClass();`** as it would remove ALL classes, which I don't want.

Answer (score 1280, accepted):

```
$("element").removeClass("class1 class2");
```

From [`removeClass()`](http://docs.jquery.com/Attributes/removeClass), the class parameter:

> One or more CSS classes to remove from
>   the elements, these are separated by
>   spaces.

Comment: As of jQuery 3.3, we can pass array of classes, like `$("element").removeClass(["class1", "class2"]);`

Answer (score 91):

```js
$('element').removeClass('class1 class2');
```

Here are [the docs](https://api.jquery.com/removeClass/).

Answer (score 22):

jQuery [`.removeClass()`](https://api.jquery.com/removeClass/) documentation.

One or more CSS classes to remove from the elements, these are separated by spaces.

Answer (score 21):

The [documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Attributes/removeClass#class) says:

> `class (Optional) String`
> One or more CSS classes to remove from the elements, these are separated by spaces.

Example:

> Remove the class 'blue' and 'under' from the matched elements.
>
> ```
> $("p:odd").removeClass("blue under");
> ```

Answer (score 19):

There are many ways can do that!

**jQuery**

1. **remove all class**
   `$("element").removeClass();`
   OR
   `$("#item").removeAttr('class');`
   OR
   `$("#item").attr('class', '');`
   OR
   `$('#item')[0].className = '';`
2. **remove multi class**
   `$("element").removeClass("class1 ... classn");`
   OR
   `$("element").removeClass("class1").removeClass("...").removeClass("classn");`

## Vanilla Javascript

1. **remove all class**

```js
// remove all items all class  
const items = document.querySelectorAll('item');
for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    items[i].className = '';
}
```

2. **remove multi class**

```js
// only remove all class of first item
const item1 = document.querySelector('item');
item1.className = '';
```

Answer (score 4):

Separate classes by white `space`

```
$('element').removeClass('class1 class2');
```

Answer (score 4):

Since jQuery [3.3.0](https://blog.jquery.com/2018/01/19/jquery-3-3-0-a-fragrant-bouquet-of-deprecations-and-is-that-a-new-feature/), it is possible to pass arrays to `.addClass()`, .`removeClass()` and `toggleClass()`, which makes it easier if there is any logic which determines which classes should be added or removed, as you don't need to mess around with the space-delimited strings.

```
$("div").removeClass(["class1", "class2"]);
```

Answer (score 2):

You must be separate those classes which you want to remove by white space`$('selector').removeClass('class1 class2');`