# jquery remove multiple classes

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Removing multiple classes (jQuery)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1485647/removing-multiple-classes-jquery)

how can we remove multiple classes from one id with in one click.

I tried like this which doesn't work properly

```
$('.clearbtn_1').click(function(){
    $('.valid_div1').removeClass('valid_tick','invalid_tick');
});
```

Comment: @DominicRodger I got solution, I though it is hard just removed comma it is working fine :)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can remove multiple classes at once by separating the classes by spaces like so :

```
$('.clearbtn_1').click(function(){
    $('.valid_div1').removeClass('valid_tick invalid_tick');
});
```

Comment: what is you have `$('.clearbtn_1').click` where you have `.clearbtn_1, 2, 3` ?

Answer (score 11):

```
$('.clearbtn_1').click(function(){
    $('.valid_div1').removeClass('valid_tick invalid_tick');
});
```

Separate the class names with a space in your single parameter of `removeClass()`.

Answer (score 4):

the removeClass function only takes one argument so use spaces to define multiple classes

```
$('.clearbtn_1').click(function(){
    $('.valid_div1').removeClass('valid_tick invalid_tick');
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried

```
$('.clearbtn_1').click(function(){
    $('.valid_div1').removeClass('valid_tick invalid_tick');
});
```

Answer (score 4):

The documentations writes it this way:

`$("p:odd").removeClass("blue under");`

Try:

```
$('.clearbtn_1').click(function(){
    $('.valid_div1').removeClass('valid_tick invalid_tick');
});
```

Ref: http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/

Answer (score 3):

I got solution, I though it is hard just removed comma it is working fine :)

```
$('.clearbtn_1').click(function(){
    $('.valid_div1').removeClass('valid_tick invalid_tick');
});
```