# jQuery: Wildcard class selector in removeClass

Tags: jquery, selector, wildcard, removeclass

This code snippet works to remove an existing class, before adding a new one, when I specify it directly (ie, 'ratingBlock', 'ratingBlock1', 'ratingBlock2', etc.). But when I use a wildcard selector in the removeClass ('[class^="ratingBlock"]'), it doesn't work. Am I doing something wrong? Thanks.

```
<style type="text/css">
.ratingBlock {background:gold !important;}
.ratingBlock1, .ratingBlock2, .ratingBlock3, .ratingBlock4, .ratingBlock5 {background:LightGreen;}
</style>

<div class="test block ratingBlock">
Broken
<div><a href="#" class="ratingLink ratingNo-1">1+</a></div>
<div><a href="#" class="ratingLink ratingNo-2">2+</a></div>
<div><a href="#" class="ratingLink ratingNo-3">3+</a></div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
// <![CDATA[
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    initRatingWorks();
});

function initRatingWorks() {
    jQuery("a.ratingLink").bind('click', function() {
      var star = jQuery(this);
      var ratingBlock = star.parents('div.test.block');
      var rating = star.attr('class').match(/\d+/);

      if (ratingBlock.attr('class').indexOf('ratingBlock') !== -1) {
          ratingBlock.removeClass('[class^="ratingBlock"]').addClass('ratingBlock' + rating);
      }
      else {
          ratingBlock.addClass('ratingBlock' + rating);
      }

      return false;
    });
}
// ]]>
</script>
```

Comment: `.removeClass` also accepts a function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$.removeClass()` doesn't take a selector as a parameter, only a class name (or class names).

See: [Removing multiple classes (jQuery)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1485656/2107024)

So you basiacally need to call:

```
$.removeClass('ratingBlock1 ratingBlock2 ratingBlock3 ratingBlock4 ratingBlock5');
```

Comment: This is what I ended up going with, because it worked. I was assuming I didn't have to list all the classes out, but since it was only five classes, and I have a short deadline, this is what I rolled with. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

`removeClass` takes either a function or a class name.  You are trying to provide a css selector.   It looks like all you need is:

```
ratingBlock.removeClass('ratingBlock').addClass('ratingBlock' + rating)
```

Furthermore you could remove a wildcard like this:

```
ratingBlock.removeClass (function (index, css) {
    return (css.match (/ratingBlock/g) || []).join(' ');
});
```

Reference: [JQuery removeClass wildcard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2644299/jquery-removeclass-wildcard)

Comment: When I add the second, wildcard solution to my code snippet example, it does not remove the existing class 'ratingBlock' from the div.test.block, it continues to just add the new class, 'ratingBlock1', 'ratingBlock2', etc.

Comment: is there an extra "\" in front of the regex `/\ratingBlock...`?

Comment: Looks like my regex is a little messed up (will fix) although the overall strategy works.

Answer (score 1):

If it makes it any easier, I [wrote a plugin for another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19059585/1037948) that will strip classes beginning (or ending) with a match, so

```
ratingBlock.stripClass('ratingBlock-').addClass('ratingBlock-' + rating);
```

will remove `ratingBlock-1` and `ratingBlock-2` but not `ratingBlock` (as long as you include the dash).

Code: https://gist.github.com/zaus/6734731

Answer (score -1):

I think your problem is the quotation marks: I don't think you need them, try omitting them.

```
'[class^=ratingBlock]'
```

**EDIT:**

`.removeClass()` accepts a class name, not a selector.

You can, however, specify multiple space separated class names, so could try this:

```
.removeClass('ratingBlock ratingBlock1 ratingBlock2');
```

http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/