# how to remove classes ending with some characters from elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I got elements with the javascript code below;

```
var elems = $("*[class*='-highlight datepick-other-month']");
```

I want to remove classes end with "-highlight" such as; red-highlight, blue-highlight and etc, from "elems".

How can I do this? All feedbacks will be appreciated!

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16039708/jquery-wildcard-class-selector-in-removeclass

Comment: You want to remove the classes from the elements, or the elements from the collection ?

Comment: classes from the elements..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this code :

```
elems.attr('class', function(_, old){
    return $.grep(old.split(/ +/), function(v){
         return !v.match(/-highlight$/);
    }).join(' ');
})
```

Working fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/zvcCL/

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the ends with selector:
http://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/

```
jQuery( "[attribute$='value']" )
```

Then call removeClass:
http://api.jquery.com/removeclass/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 $( "a[hreflang|='en']" ).css( "border", "3px dotted green" );
```

Also see [attributeContainsPrefix selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-prefix-selector/).

Answer (score 0):

here is how you select elements that end with a keyword: [jQuery Ends With](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/)

and here is how you select elements inside `elems`:

```
$([what],[where])
```

so you would want to do this:

```
var elems = $("*[class*='-highlight datepick-other-month']");
$("*[class$='-highlight']",elems).remove();
```

this is how you remove the elements from the document.

 if you want however, to exclude those elements from your `elems` var, you can just exclude them as follows:

```
var elems = $("*[class*='-highlight datepick-other-month']").not("[class$='-highlight']");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove those classes using regexp:

```
$.each($("*[class*='-highlight']"), function() {
  $(this)[0].className = $(this)[0].className.replace(/\b.*-highlight\b/g, '');  
});
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/wzQFT/