# Remove Class from DIV found using partial match

Tags: jquery, html

I have a div with a class which I need to switch out based on what the user is interacting with.

```
<div class="book-chapter-name chapter2" data-lhg="chapter-info">
    <span>Chapter String Here</span>
</div>
```

I have the current div in a jQuery object and this has been found using:

```
$('div[class*="chapter"]')
```

What I want to do is remove the existing class and insert a new class so that `chapter2` becomes `chapter3`

```
var chapterString = $('#page'+page).attr('data-lhg-chapter'),
    chapterNumber = $('#page'+page).attr('data-lhg-chapter-number'),
    chapterInfo = $('[data-lhg="chapter-info"]');

if($('div[class*="chapter"]')){
    $('div[class*="chapter"]').removeClass('chapter[0-9]');
}

$(chapterInfo).text(chapterString).addClass('chapter'+chapterNumber);
```

This doesn't seem to work, I think it is to do with the string passed to `removeClass` but I am not sure what to put in there to get the right result.

Comment: Have a look at the second answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16039708/jquery-wildcard-class-selector-in-removeclass - use a function and regex to remove the class

Comment: The function `removeClass` looks in your case for css class 'chapter[0-9]'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove all classes and add them back again with changed number.

```
$('div[class*="chapter"]').removeClass();
```

And then

```
$(chapterInfo).text(chapterString).addClass("book-chapter-name").addClass('chapter'+chapterNumber);
```

Comment: Thanks! a really elegant solution should have seen it myself.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> $('div[class^="chapter"]')
> ```

```
[attribute^=value]
```

`div[class^="https"]` Selects every `<div>` element whose `class` attribute value begins with `"chapter"`