# How to remove class of li if there is using multiple classes in li

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-ui, html-lists

**The HTML Code**

```
echo  "<ul id='sub'>";
if($Set == null){ 
echo '<li class="BlankSeat" ></li>';
}
```

**if in database status yes or no add class in red color**

```
elseif($status == 'no' || $status == 'yes'){
echo '<li class="occupied" title="Row'.$val1.'" name="'.$val2.'" 
value="'.$val3.'"></li>'; 
 }
 elseif($name=='PINK'){
echo '<li class="pink" title="Row'.$val1.'" name="'.val2.'" 
value="'.$val3.'"></li>';
}
elseif($name=='YELLOW'){
echo '<li class="yellow" title="Row'.$val1.'" name="'.$val2.'" 
value="'.$val3.'"></li>';
 }
else{
 echo '<li class="orange" title="Row'.$val1.'" name="'.$val2.'" 
 value="'.$val3.'"></li>';
 }
echo "</ul>";   
}
echo '</div>';
}
else
{
 echo "No result Available";
 }
```

**This is my code**

```
$('li').click(function(e) {
var $this = $(this);
```

**First part where iam adding class when click on one of them**

```
if($(this).hasClass('pink')|| $(this).hasClass('yellow') || 
$(this).hasClass('orange'))
{
$(this).addClass('Booked').removeClass('pink','yellow','orange');
}
```

**Here i want to remove the booked class with only which one is clicked**

```
else
{
$(this).addClass('pink').removeClass('Booked');
$(this).addClass('yellow').removeClass('Booked');
$(this).addClass('orange').removeClass('Booked');
}}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Removing multiple classes (jQuery)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1485647/removing-multiple-classes-jquery)

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen sir  
first part is okay.but in else part when Booked class is active ,now when i again click on Booked ,after that the same class should be added which last time changed

Comment: please include all relevant code, (html) else its very hard to help you

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen sir. Check my html code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```js
$(document).on("click", "li", function(e) {
   if($(this).hasClass('pink')|| $(this).hasClass('yellow') || $(this).hasClass('orange')){
      $(this).toggleClass("Booked")
      console.log($(this).attr("class"))
   }
})
```

```css
.pink{
  background-color:pink;
}
.yellow{
  background-color:yellow;
}
.orange{
  background-color:orange;
}
.Booked{
  background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id='sub'>
  <li class="BlankSeat"> Item 3</li>
  <li class="occupied"> Item 3</li>
  <li class="pink"> Item 3</li>
  <li class="yellow"> Item 4</li>
  <li class="orange"> Item 5</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: not working sir.when i agin clicking on Booked class it change the class orange only

Comment: Updated answer, hope it helps

Comment: else part not working sir.. change the class as orange only

Comment: How do u want exactly add 3 classes color? Obviusly only work last class color. Tell whats exactly you need to help you please

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154199/discussion-between-krish-and-silversurfer).

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
$(this).addClass('Booked').removeClass('pink yellow orange');
```

[See help here](https://api.jquery.com/removeclass/)

Edit:

Sample JS to my comment below

```
if($(this).hasClass('pink') || 
   $(this).hasClass('yellow') || 
   $(this).hasClass('orange')) {
    $(this).addClass('Booked');
} else if($(this).hasClass('Booked')) {
    $(this).removeClass('Booked');
}
```

Sample CSS to my comment below

```
.Booked {
    background-color: blue !important; // whatever style your .Booked should have
}
```

Comment: first part is okay.but in else part when Booked class is active ,now when i again click on Booked ,after that the same class should be added  which last time changed

Comment: Well if you want to restore the previous class you can go with this: Add Booked class on click, but do not remove pink yellow orange. Now .Booked should style the <li> with !important styles

Comment: Added a sample above